# Power BI - use measure in direct query

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have the following measure that is shown in a Card:

MinDate = min('MyDateTable'[theDate])

This is shown in a Card that updates when I move the slicer (style = After) on my MyDateTable.

I would like to use this measure (MinDate) in a direct query that I have on a table:

This is what I have tried:

let

dynamicDate = MinDate,

filterQuery = "Select A, B,C from aTable where date = '" & dynamicDate & "'",

Source = Sql.Database("srvr","database",

[Query = filterQuery])

in

Source

This works fine when I use a parameter in place of MinDate but I need to get the values from the measure.

Answer (score 1):

Power Query is a layer below DAX. You can't use elements created with DAX (measures, calculated columns, etc.) in M.

You have to either change your query and change the filtering logic (Power BI will take care to fetch only the data matching the filter - see [query folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding)) or use something else, like [dynamic M query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters) for example.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work since I'm using a direct query (stored procedure). The issue is that I want a date picker rather than a drop-down list of dates (which I currently have and works fine) its just not a great user experience. This seems like Power Bi users have been asking for this functionality for a while. If you have an actual example that shows how this will work with a direct query that would be helpful.

Comment: Small correction - I meant to say `Dynamic M query parameters`. Having the report logic in a stored procedure is very bad practice for building Power BI reports. It limits the flexibility a lot (as you already notice). The right approach is to move the logic from the SP f.e. to the Power BI report itself or to change the SP to be table valued UDF. Otherwise, one possible hack is to use linked server and OPENROWSET. I will post few links as separate comments, because the length of a single comment is not enough.

Comment: [Dynamic M query parameters in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters)

Comment: [TSQL Table-Valued Functions And Dynamic M Parameters In Power BI DirectQuery](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2022/02/20/tsql-table-valued-functions-and-dynamic-m-parameters-in-power-bi-directquery/)

Comment: [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: [SQL Stored Procedure With Dynamic Parameter In Power BI Service by TAIK18](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1En6_NB_dY)

Comment: The linked you sent are what I have used so far as well. For my case since amount of data is extremely large I need to use a stored procedure. I use OpenQuery rather than openrowset. I was just looking for some workaround while the community waits for a datepicker to be added to power bi.